# Why doesn't echidna capture failure when Roles are used?

Tags: solidity, echidna

I'm having this test, which deliberately introduces a failure of integer overflow, which is usually captured with Echidna.
[image]

```
function inc(uint256 val) public {
    unchecked {
        counter += val;
    }
}
```

However, if the same code is used with Roles, then the error is not getting captured.

```
function inc(uint256 val) public onlyRole(INCREMENTOR_ROLE) {
    unchecked {
        counter += val;
    }
}
```

The test is:

```
contract EchidnaIncrementorTest is TestIncrementor {

    constructor () {
        _grantRole(INCREMENTOR_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function echidna_test_inc() public view returns (bool) {
        return (checkCounter() >= 2 ** 100);
    }
}
```